# Apply XSLT to camelcase specific elements in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get three XML elements camel cased using XSLT and am just not connecting the dots on how to apply the XSLT templates to the specific elements.

Here is an example of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<jsi:CitationCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:j="http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:jsi="http://www.justicesystems.com/iepd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.justicesystems.com/iepd extension-schema.xsd">
  <jsi:CitationDocument>
    <nc:Person>
        <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName>FIRST NAME</nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonMiddleName>MIDDLE NAME</nc:PersonMiddleName>
            <nc:PersonSurName>LAST NAME</nc:PersonSurName>
          </nc:PersonName>
    </nc:Person>
  </jsi:CitationDocument>
</jsi:CitationCollection>
```

Here is my current XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template name="CamelCase">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($text,' ')">
      <xsl:call-template name="CamelCaseWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text,' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
      <xsl:call-template name="CamelCase">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text,' ')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:call-template name="CamelCaseWord">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CamelCaseWord">
  <xsl:param name="text"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text,1,1),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" /><xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($text,2,string-length($text)-1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is what I want:

```
<jsi:CitationCollection>
  <jsi:CitationDocument>
    <nc:Person>
        <nc:PersonName>
            <nc:PersonGivenName>First Name</nc:PersonGivenName>
            <nc:PersonMiddleName>Middle Name</nc:PersonMiddleName>
            <nc:PersonSurName>Last Name</nc:PersonSurName>
          </nc:PersonName>
    </nc:Person>
  </jsi:CitationDocument>
</jsi:CitationCollection>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "how to apply the XSLT templates to the specific elements"? Which are the specific elements? Match them with the template e.g. `<xsl:template name="CamelCase" match="*[not(*)]"><xsl:param name="text" select="."/>...</xsl:template>`.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly are you trying to accomplish here. What is the expected result of transforming the given example?

Comment: Ok, I added what I want. @michael.hor257k

Comment: That's not camel case; that's just capitalizing the first character (of every word?). -- P.S. Please fix your input to be a well-formed XML; you can;t have a prefix without binding it to a namespace.

Comment: Ok, adjusted examples more... Just caps first letter of every word will suffice @michael.hor257k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you try it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" name="capitalize-words">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="uppercase">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="lowercase">abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="word" select="substring-before(concat($text, ' '), ' ')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 1, 1), $lowercase, $uppercase)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word, 2), $uppercase, $lowercase)" />
    <xsl:if test="contains($text, ' ')">
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <!-- recursive call -->
        <xsl:call-template name="capitalize-words">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that this will backfire with names like `Anne-Nicolle` or  `d'Angelo` or `MacNamara`.

Comment: Ok cool, thank you.  I agree about d'Angelo and MacNamara, would you suggest an alternative way that is more robust?  Also, I cut out a lot of other elements that exist in the XML for brevity, I think I can get to what I want with what you have though.  I don't think I want to apply this to all text elements which if I read this right that is what it is doing.

Comment: You can add a template matching the elements you want to capitalize and call the capitalizing template by name from there (remove the `match-"text()"` part). -- I don't know a way to make this really "robust"; you can add more delimiters, but you need human intelligence to differentiate MacNamara from Macintosh. And there is no way to tell if MACDONALD was MacDonald or Macdonald.

Comment: I agree, it gets dicey.  I will mess around and figure out how to apply it to just certain elements, I appreciate you getting me unstuck.

Comment: I am not sure what your use case is, but I generally advise clients in similar situation to leave well enough alone. People are sensitive to their names being misspelled.

Comment: I hear you my use case is we take this XML import it into a system and then people go thru each record one by one and proper case names.  This at least gets them a little closer to the end goal.

Comment: Well, this should give you a good starting point. But it can never be guaranteed to be perfect because, as I said, some of the information is lost forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can match your template on text nodes with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CamelCase" match="text()[normalize-space()]">
    <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, ' ')">
            <xsl:call-template name="CamelCaseWord">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text, ' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="CamelCase">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, ' ')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="CamelCaseWord">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="CamelCaseWord">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:value-of
        select="translate(substring($text, 1, 1), 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')"/>
    <xsl:value-of
        select="translate(substring($text, 2), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"
    />
</xsl:template>
```